# Inserting SAS datetime into Teradata using proc sql

Tags: datetime, sas, timestamp, teradata

I have a SAS datetime stored in a macro variable and try to write that into a timestamp column in teradata using proc sql. E.g. I can write that into a string column with %BQUOTE('&macrovariable') and it returns  14APR2020:06:47:20. But I am failing to convert that into a timestamp and write into timestamp field in teradata. Cast as timestamp did also not work :( It returns ERROR: Teradata execute: Invalid timestamp.

My Code: 
INSERT INTO MYTABLEWITHDATETIMEFIELD
        VALUES (
                %BQUOTE('&macrovariable')
               )

Could you help me out? THANKS!

Best regards
Flo

Comment: Can you format your timestamp string differently?  The typical format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, something like `TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 12:00:00'`.  Take a look at https://docs.teradata.com/reader/S0Fw2AVH8ff3MDA0wDOHlQ/~27tNOMzjYMsPBYRi53xdQ

Comment: I tried it both while initially filling the macrovariable and whithin a cast in the insert statement the way you described :( or where would you place the format statement? thanks anyway!

Comment: Why is the value in a macro variable? Why not just keep the value in a variable in a dataset and append the data to the table?

Comment: Try `CAST('14APR2020:06:47:20' AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'DDMMMYYYY:HH:MM:SS'`.  You just need to get your timestamp "pieces" to match your format string so Teradata understands how to build the timestamp value.

Comment: Minor correction: use MI for minutes component `INSERT INTO MYTABLEWITHDATETIMEFIELD VALUES(CAST(%BQUOTE('&macrovariable') AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'DDMMMYYYY:HH:MI:SS') )`. Probably needs to be submitted as a database-specific EXECUTE pass-through statement.

Comment: Oops, thanks Fred.  I keep mixing up `MM` with `MI`.

Comment: Thank you guys! 
INSERT INTO MYTABLEWITHDATETIMEFIELD VALUES(CAST(%BQUOTE('&macrovariable') AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'DDMMMYYYY:HH:MI:SS') )

works great! I had the wrong format, but with MMM its working! :-) you made my day!